# Is it safe to view moon at daytime through telescope

Tags: the-moon, telescope

I have a little 76mm Newtonian Reflector. I want to see the moon at daytime. Is it safe to look at sky at daytime when sun is shinning or there is any risk of sun.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't directly look at the sun through your telescope, then there is no problem. But don't try to see the moon during solar eclipse without special filters (easily available for your telescope's eyepieces)

In  my telescope, I have seen the moon day time when there was very light cloud cover. It was awesome scene. You can feel that the moon is spherical by observing its terminator and the lighted edge. You can easily make out the dark side edge.

Comment: *NEVER* use an eye piece only solar filter.  The concentrated heat makes them prone to overheating and cracking; letting enough light through to cause blindness.  Safe solar filters go at the front of the scope and attenuate the incoming light before any of the optics concentrate it.

Comment: @DanNeely I tried one of those eyepiece solar filters once. The heat cracked it. Quick reflexes saved my eyesight.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good time to view the moon is before the sky is fully light,say 8am.The pupil of the eye will no be fully dilated and better eye/lens will give improved resolution(f ratio).In addition to this an improved contrast will be achieved as the atmosphere has less reflected light relative to the optical system of the telescope.
A friend and I agreed more detail  of the moon could be seen to the naked eye under these conditios

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to observe anything during the day, as long as you don't point the telescope close to the Sun. Just stay away from the Sun and you'll be fine. Be careful to not accidentally swing the tube in the direction of the Sun.

E.g. Mercury is pretty hard to observe at other times than during the day (or dusk), and yet astronomers have been observing it for a very long time.

One trick that works is to stay in the shade of a tall building, therefore screening off the Sun, but obviously in such a manner that the object you want to observe is still visible. You can almost always do this, unless the object is very close to the Sun, in which case you may want to cancel that observation altogether.